# Debugging Syntax error: "}" unexpected (expecting "fi")

Tags: shell-script, services

The service for a piece of software I just installed (from a provided `.deb` file) on a Ubuntu server won't start. When running the service I get the error:

```
/etc/init.d/matrixsa: 44: Syntax error: "}" unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

Here is the relevant part of the script. Not being versed in shell scripting I don't know if this is valid:

```
if [ -f /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions ]
then
    . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
else
    function action {
        echo "$1"
        shift
        $@
    } # <-- this is line 44
    function success {
        echo -n "Success"
    }
    function failure {
        echo -n "Failed"
    }
fi
```

Comment: Are you running it with bash or plain sh? See [this list of bashisms](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh#function)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`$@` could contain anything, even things which make your function suddenly syntactically invalid. Quote it instead. Here is a less breakable version of the script:

```
if [ -f /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions ]; then
    . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
else
    action() {
        printf '%s\n' "$1"
        shift
        "$@"
    }
    success() { printf Success ; }
    failure() { printf Failed ; }
fi
```

If you are using `bash` or similar, you could use the following as the `action` function:

```
action() {
    printf '%s\n' "$1"
    "${@:2}"
}
```

If it is important that it splits on IFS like the original script (it probably isn't), unquote `$@`.

It's also possible that you're running this in a non-bash shell. `function` is a bashism, use `func()` instead.

Comment: +1, `"$@"` probably has the single largest utility/use factor of all the Bash idioms. Use More Quotes :)